# Getting extra brackets using array push

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to build a small custom logger and I am noticing with my array push that I am getting extra brackets and cannot figure out what is going on. Here is the sample output

```
{
"GuestCheckout": [
    {
        "log": "Product Id: 78-1212121",
        "screenshot": ""
    },
    [
        {
            "log": "Product Color: undefined Product Size: 6 Lb Qty: 2",
            "screenshot": ""
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "log": "",
            "screenshot": "results/screenshots/Guest Checkout - Failed.jpg"
        }
    ]
]
}
```

Here is the class that has the logger function

```
var logs = {},
curLogs = [];

module.exports = {
    logger: function(log, screenshot) {
      isScreenshot = screenshot || "false";
      curTestName = testName.replace(/ /g,'');
      curLogs = [];

      if (isScreenshot == "true") {
        curLogs.push({
            "log": "",
            "screenshot": log
        });
      } else {
        curLogs.push({
            "log": log,
            "screenshot": ""
        });
      }

      if (curTestName in logs) {
        logs[curTestName].push(curLogs);
      } else {
        logs[curTestName] = curLogs;
      }

      console.log(curLogs);
    }
}
```

You will notice with the first log and screenshot that its wrapped around {} but the second instances in wrapped with []. This logger function is called multiple times. I think is has to do with the way push is building this but I could be wrong. Thanks

UPDATE: With the one solution the output looks like this now

```
{
  "GuestCheckout": [
    [
        {
            "log": "Product Id: 36-5173230",
            "screenshot": ""
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "log": "Product Color: undefined Product Size: 6 Lb Qty: 2",
            "screenshot": ""
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "log": "",
            "screenshot": "results/screenshots/Guest Checkout - Failed.jpg"
        }
    ]
  ]
}
```

The problem is now all the {logs, screenshots} are wrapped in brackets.

Comment: Can you show the code that calls the logger function? What is the source and type of data passed to it?

Comment: common.logger("Product Id: " + product.id);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue starts when you log something to a test that already exists. If the log already exists, you are pushing an array rather than an object. To fix this, you have two options. Either pull the existing array for the test and push to it directly, or, push each new log entry to the test afterwards.

```
var logs = {},
curLogs = [];

module.exports = {
    logger: function(log, screenshot) {
      isScreenshot = screenshot || "false";
      curTestName = testName.replace(/ /g,'');
      if (!logs[curTestName]) {
        // initialize logs entry
        logs[curTestName] = [];
      }
      // get logs entry
      curLogs = logs[curTestName];

      if (isScreenshot == "true") {
        curLogs.push({
            "log": "",
            "screenshot": log
        });
      } else {
        curLogs.push({
            "log": log,
            "screenshot": ""
        });
      }
      console.log(curLogs);
    }
}
```

or

```
var logs = {},
curLogs = [];

module.exports = {
    logger: function(log, screenshot) {
      isScreenshot = screenshot || "false";
      curTestName = testName.replace(/ /g,'');
      curLogs = [];

      if (isScreenshot == "true") {
        curLogs.push({
            "log": "",
            "screenshot": log
        });
      } else {
        curLogs.push({
            "log": log,
            "screenshot": ""
        });
      }

      if (curTestName in logs) {
        Array.push.apply(logs[curTestName], curLogs);
      } else {
        logs[curTestName] = curLogs;
      }

      console.log(curLogs);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is its adding the brackets to all of them now. I dont want those brackets

Comment: it shouldn't be. you should have `{testName: [{log: "log", screenshot: ""},{log: "log", screenshot: ""},{log: "log", screenshot: ""}]}` showing three logs for test `testName`

Answer (score 1):

You are defined carlog as an array. In the first step you are pushing an object to the array. That's why there is no []. In the 2nd and 3rd steps you are pushing an array to carlog. That's why there is [].

Comment: And to correct it, you need to merge `curLogs` into `logs[curTestName]` rather than pushing. `Array.push.apply(logs[curTestName], curLogs);`

Comment: Kevin what would that change by doing this?

Comment: the outcome is the same as doing `logs[curTestName].push({log:"",etc})` instead of `curLogs.push({log:"",etc})`

Comment: So you want me to replace logs[curTestName] = curLogs; with what you are suggesting?

Comment: No, I went ahead and made it an answer so i can show code samples easier. The suggestion i was making is shown in the second code snippet, the first is better.